# PHP GD Library and image manipulation with AJAX or jQuery

Tags: php, ajax, gd

I have a successfully working interface that I programmed using PHP GD Library where a user can enter multiple lines of text and when the user clicks "submit" it overlays the text they typed onto a png background.

Is it possible to do the same thing but use AJAX in the process?  I'd like to somehow let each input field filled out automatically do an onblur, and trigger an AJAX script.  That way they see the data entered into the fields change the image on the fly.

Normally when using AJAX, it sends a success callback to an input field, alert, or sets it into a DIV.  Would I place the entire GD Library code into the PHP POST page and process it there, then somehow send the compiled PNG image to the AJAX success callback?

I'm just needing a general idea as to if it's possible, and the basic outline as to how I'd go about solving this.  Thank you!

EDIT:  Here is the last bit of code used to display the image after the text has been overlayed.

```
imagepng( $my_img, "./images/$form_token.png");
imagedestroy( $my_img );
```

Will this code end up on the PHP processing page that AJAX POSTS to?  Or do I process  the image with the GD Library functions and then somehow pass this image as an img src.  Will I save it to my server, then display the img src that was saved as the AJAX success callback?  I'm confused because I thought AJAX loaded things instantly without refreshing the page but will that still happen if saving the file to the server, then showing it in an image placeholder?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.

You may use **[jQuery AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)** to do this.

1. Create a php file to respond to the Ajax data from the web page using jQuery, either by `POST` or `GET` method.
2. Make the php file return a success message on successful processing on data, and you may program something in your JavaScript to display success message.

You can read a tutorial here [www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_ajax.asp](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_ajax.asp)

Hope this helps..

Comment: I think the only part that is very unclear to me is where or how do I display the actual image that is generated with the background and text that is overlayed?  Currently all the code is on one page because I haven't integrated the jQuery AJAX yet.  The end of the image processing code shows "imagepng" code which I'll paste in my post above.